# While loop and palindrome of a number in a given range

Tags: c

In the following program  can i declare while(temp = num) instead of declaring temp=num; at first . I did try that the program executed without any errors but didnt print the values , I want to know why ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num, r, sum, temp;
    int min, max;

    printf("Enter the minimum range: "); // take minimum value to start
    scanf("%d", &min);

    printf("Enter the maximum range: "); // max value to start`**enter code here**`
    scanf("%d", &max);

    printf("Palindrome numbers in given range are: ");
    for (num = min; num <= max; num++)
    {
        temp = num;
        sum = 0;
        while (temp)
        {
            r = temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
            sum = sum * 10 + r;
        }
        if (num == sum)
            printf("%d ", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debugger...........

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, fix that first.

Comment: And there is no C/C++, what language are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: _can i declare `while(temp = num)`_  You can but it would not work. The `while` loop would never end. Or never start if `num == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program likely isn't printing because you do not ever print the newline character `\n` which will flush the buffer to stdout, nor are you manually flushing with `fflush()`. I would try flushing at the end of your loop, or if you do in fact need a new line, just print a new line with `printf("\n");`

In regards to setting temp = num at the start of your `while-loop`, you probably want to use another `for-loop` such as `for (temp = num; temp; temp/=10)`.

Putting it all together, the tail end of your program may look like this:

```
for (num = min; num <= max; num++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (temp = num; temp; temp/=10)
    {
        r = temp % 10;
        sum = sum * 10 + r;
    }
    if (num == sum)
        printf("%d ", num);
}
fflush(stdout);
return 0;
```

Comment: using the debugger solved the problem thank you . If I add temp=num in the while() it made it endles

Comment: @IronVergil do you understand why `while(temp=num)` is an infinite loop in your case?